# Postgres "for Each" RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm using sequelize, and I have a function that uses findOrCreate, however it seems to throw and error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" despite sometimes adding the entries.

The code I use is below, and I am passing it 6 tids.  Does anyone know whats going on and how to resolve/prevent this?

```
exports.sqlAddTags = async function(did, tids) {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        const promises = [];
        tids.forEach(t =>{
            console.log(did, t)
            promises.push(FB_Tag.findOrCreate({
                where: {
                    did: did,
                    tid: t
                }
            }));
        });
        return await Promise.all(promises);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
};
```

My model:

```
FB_Tag.init({
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    did: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    tid: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'fb_tag',
    timestamps: false
});
```

EDIT:  Seems with just 1 tid, it also throws this error

If the item already exists, I seem to get this message. Not sure if this is normal?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.testfunc(OUT response "public"."fb_tags", OUT sequelize_caught_exception text) RETURNS RECORD AS $func_66aef14340b2417dabf18d3cdfafa589$ BEGIN INSERT INTO "public"."fb_tags" ("i
d","did","tid") VALUES (DEFAULT,'jcBUnwocFS9I7RekMZHJ','7AQS1zPkLIUsSfx8lC0a') RETURNING * INTO response; EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS sequelize_caught_exception = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL; END $func_66aef14340b2417dabf18d3cdfafa589$ LANG
UAGE plpgsql; SELECT (testfunc.response).*, testfunc.sequelize_caught_exception FROM pg_temp.testfunc(); DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS pg_temp.testfunc();
```

I've created a test script with the same logic as above that works, so I can only put this down to be how the function is called..

```
const newTags = [];
const oldTags = [];
const postgresTags = []
data.tags.forEach(t => {
    if(t.id === t.title) {
        newTags.push(t.title)
    } else {
        oldTags.push(t.id);
        postgresTags.push(t.id)
    }
});
if(oldTags.length > 0) {
    await firestoreAddTagsToDesign(context.auth.uid, oldTags, data.did, "old");
}
if(newTags.length > 0) {
    const setTags = await firestoreAddNewTags(context.auth.uid, newTags, data.did);
    await firestoreAddTagsToDesign(context.auth.uid, setTags,  data.did, "new");
    setTags.forEach(i => postgresTags.push(i.id));
}
await sqlAddTags(data.did, postgresTags);
```

Comment: This error indicates an endless loop in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Im not sure how. I've logged out the loop and everything around it and it only executes the function once, and the loop with the length of the array i pass it

Comment: I'd log the SQL statements that are actually executed and start there.

Comment: Just added something that logs out, i'm not sure if this is normal behaviour for Postgres though?

Comment: That SQL statement doesn't seem to have a connection to the error message.

Comment: I think that might be a Sequelize findOrCreate response.  I've got another test script that logs the same message. Test script works fine so maybe its how its being called. Have updated question

Comment: Some things unrelated to your error: 1. there's almost never a need to `return await` a promise. 2. instead of using `forEach` to push onto an array you can just `map` a promise-returning function over the list of ids and call `Promise.all` on that.